# Cannot access error message from auth.service in another component/ Angular 4

Tags: angular, error-handling, promise, firebase-authentication

In my app, I have `auth.service` where I successfully get access to both `.then` and `.catch` methods on Firebase `signInWithEmailAndPassword`. However, then I need to somehow access this `errorMsg` variable in another component to display error messages to users depending on different properties brought by this `errorMsg`.

However, once I try to access it from another component, I always get this:

```
' Cannot read property 'catch' of undefined'
```

**Auth.Service.Ts**

```
  errorMsg: Promise<string>;
    signinUser(email: string, password: string) {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(
            response => {
              this.router.navigate(['/movies']);
              firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
                .then(
                  (token: string) => this.token = token
                );
                this.getCurrentUser(firebase.auth().currentUser);
                this.isLogout = false;
            }
          )
          .catch(
            error => {
              this.errorMsg = error;
              console.log(this.errorMsg);
            }
          );
      }
```

**SignIn.Component.Ts**

```
 errorMsg
onSignin(form: NgForm) {
    const email = form.value.email;
    const password = form.value.password;
    this.authService.signinUser(email, password);
    this.authService.errorMsg.catch(error => this.errorMsg = error);
  }
```

**SignIn.Component.Ts after amendments**

```
 get errorMsg(): string {
    this.errorAlert = this.authService.errorMsg;
    this.errorAlert !== '' ? this.errorAlert = this.errorAlert.replace('Error: ', '') : this.errorAlert = '';
    return this.authService.errorMsg;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

**Auth.Service.Ts**

```
  errorMsg: string;   // Simple string

  signinUser(email: string, password: string) {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(
            response => {
              this.router.navigate(['/movies']);
              firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
                .then(
                  (token: string) => this.token = token
                );
                this.getCurrentUser(firebase.auth().currentUser);
                this.isLogout = false;
            }
          )
          .catch(
            error => {
              this.errorMsg = error;
              console.log(this.errorMsg);
            }
          );
      }
```

**SignIn.Component.Ts**

```
 get errorMsg(): string {
    return this.authService.errorMsg;
 ]

 onSignin(form: NgForm) {
    const email = form.value.email;
    const password = form.value.password;
    this.authService.signinUser(email, password);

  }
```

Something like this should work if errorMsg is bound in the template.

Angular's built-in change detection notices the change, rebinds, and calls the getter which will always get the current value of the error message from the service.

**SignIn.Component.Ts after amendments**

```
 get errorMsg(): string {
    this.errorAlert = this.authService.errorMsg;
    this.errorAlert = this.errorAlert ? this.errorAlert.replace('Error: ', '') : '';
    return this.errorAlert;
  }
```

Comment: well , I implemented it and if works provided Ido not wish to edit errorMsg before displaying in the template. whenever i try to edit the messege i get 'Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined   '   do you know any workaround ?                                                         
                    

 get errorMsg(): string {
    this.errorAlert = this.authService.errorMsg;
    this.errorAlert !== '' ? this.errorAlert = this.errorAlert.replace('Error: ', '') : this.errorAlert = '';
    return this.authService.errorMsg;
  }

Comment: i added **SignIn.Component.Ts after amendments** in my question above to better display the amended .ts code

Comment: I don't think your syntax was quite right `!== ''` won't correctly check for null or undefined. See my updated answer.

Comment: this time i get 'this.errorAlert.replace is not a function' whenever i hit 'submit' button

Comment: I just added the above `get errorMsg()` to stackblitz and it seemed to work fine. Here it is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-du7wtf Consider adding a bit more of your code to this stackblitz so we can see where there may be another problem.